Enable Data-up mode to BLE device, using AT commands
I am developing a UWA project with Visual Studio and C#, using the WIndows.Devices.Bluetooth standard library, which:
Connects to a BLE device

The BLE module embedded into the device is BGX220P
The device, have a Data-up mode, where collect data from several IoT devices and send them to the Central.

The transmission and the reception of data between the application and the device is made through the Characteristic TX and RX

The data transfer from Central to Periferic is made through Characteristic RX
The data transfer from Periferic to Central is made through Characteristic TX

The application try to send AT commands to Characteristic RX, and collect the data, listening the Characteristc TX ValueChanged event listener.
The problem is that an error Unreachable is returned when I try to write the AT command to enable Data-up mode of the devices (the error occur whatever I am trying to write) so collection of data can start. When I try to write bytes (e.x. set the buffer size), works fine.
My code to write the commands:
private async Task SendATCommandAsync(string command)
{
    command += "\r\n"; // Add the command termination
    var data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(command);
    await rxCharacteristic.WriteValueAsync(data.AsBuffer()); 
}

My code to initialize to BLE service and characteristics:
    try
    {
        var result = await bleDevice.GetGattServicesAsync();

        if (result.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
        {
            var services = result.Services;
            var service = services.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Uuid == serviceUuid);

            if (service != null) 
            {
                var characteristicsResult = await service.GetCharacteristicsAsync();

                if (characteristicsResult.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                {
                    var characteristics = characteristicsResult.Characteristics;
                    rxCharacteristic = characteristics.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Uuid == rxCharacteristicUuid);
                    txCharacteristic = characteristics.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Uuid == txCharacteristicUuid);

                // Set up event handler for characteristic value changes
                txCharacteristic.ValueChanged += TxCharacteristic_ValueChanged; 

                    // Enable Notify 
                    await txCharacteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(
                        GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);

            rxCharacteristic.ProtectionLevel = GattProtectionLevel.EncryptionRequired;
                    await SendATCommandAsync("ATI"); // Example AT command 
                }
            }
        } 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
         // ... handle exceptions ...
    }

More information are available if needed. Can anybody help, please?
I am using the BluetoothLE demo solution, to handle BLE device scanning and connection.
